# Running an executable from bash script

Tags: bash, dos

My apologies if the question is naive.

Is it possible to run a few lines in a bash script then execute a dos batch file and a dos executable file, after completing the execution of the batch file and executable file, continue executing the rest of the lines in the bash script?

Can I do this using *dosemu*?

Comment: I guess it should be moved to superuser.com ..

Comment: @PiotrWadas : I'm somewhat new here. I don't know where this question should belong. If you are sure then I will move it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's fine - you can connect your StackExchange account with the one on SuperUser. I would move it, but I think I don't have enough reputation to perform moving :)

Comment: @PiotrWadas : Yes, I think moderators help is needed to move this to superuser.com. Please see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46240/how-to-move-a-question-from-superuser-to-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

A bash script will always finish the script after completion of any called script or executable. example:

```
@echo off
echo hello
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
echo hope you had fun browsing the web!
pause
```

This will always echo the last line of code as soon as firefox is closed.

Comment: Is it possible to run a windows application directly from linux console without having an emulator or something? Is this working for you? I am getting an error "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" command not found.

Comment: Linux is an operating system. A batch script runs in cmd. Make sure it is the correct path to firefox, or whatever application you want to run.